# How to differentiate when "second field" is missing in LocalDateTime

Tags: time, java-8, localtime, date-parsing, localdate

I am given `LocalDateTime` object created from `String`. I want to check whether that original string has "seconds" parameter or not.
My two inputs are:

```
String a = "2016-06-22T10:01"; //not given
String b = "2016-06-22T10:01:00"; //not given

LocalDateTime dateA = LocalDateTime.parse(a, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
LocalDateTime dateB = LocalDateTime.parse(b, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
```

Problem is I am given `dateA` and `dateB`, not `a` and `b`.

I have tried various ways like converting `LocalDateTime` to `String` and finding its length. For that I used two approaches.

```
date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME).length();
date.toString().length();
```

But first approach gives length 19 for both `dateA` and `dateB`  whereas second approach gives length 16 for both `dateA` and `dateB`.

I am unable to find any way to differentiate `dateA` and `dateB`.

Comment: There is actually no difference between these `LocalDateTime`s, since missing seconds mean that they're zero.

Answer (score 4):

As other people have already said, a `LocalDateTime`-object has always a second part. The other question is **if the original input has got a second part or not**. It is possible to find out the answer with only Java-8-means (but it is ugly because it is based on exception control flow):

```
String a = "2016-06-22T10:01"; // not given
String b = "2016-06-22T10:01:00"; // given

boolean hasSecondPart;
try {
    TemporalAccessor tacc =
        DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parseUnresolved(a, new ParsePosition(0));
    tacc.get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE);
    hasSecondPart = true;
} catch (UnsupportedTemporalTypeException ex) {
    hasSecondPart = false;
}
System.out.println(hasSecondPart); // true for input b, false for input a
```

---

Side note:

An exception-free check if the string input has a second part or not would be possible with my library [Time4J](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/format/expert/ChronoFormatter.html#parseRaw-java.lang.String-) using this code:

```
boolean hasSecondPart =
    Iso8601Format.EXTENDED_DATE_TIME.parseRaw(a).contains(PlainTime.SECOND_OF_MINUTE);
```

Answer (score 2):

In [`ISO_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_DATE_TIME), **seconds** are optional (and **set to zero if not present**), that's why it parses both inputs. And [`LocalDateTime.toString()` method will print the **seconds** only if it's not zero](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString--).

So, once you have the `LocalDateTime` objects created, you can't know if the original `String` had the **seconds** field.

---

To validate if the **seconds** field is present in the input `String`, you must create your own pattern and check if it throws exception when parsing:

```
// formatter with required seconds
DateTimeFormatter withSecs = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

LocalDateTime.parse(b, withSecs); // OK
LocalDateTime.parse(a, withSecs); // DateTimeParseException
```

---

If you want just to check if the field is present, but don't want to build a `LocalDateTime` object, you can also use `parseUnresolved` method, which doesn't throw exceptions:

```
ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);
withSecs.parseUnresolved(a, position);
if(position.getErrorIndex() == -1) {
    System.out.println("No error (it contains seconds)"); // b gets here
} else {
    System.out.println("Error (it does not contain seconds)"); // a gets here
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works with a fixed pattern, but if the pattern has an optional part (like used in `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME`) then the method `parseUnresolved()` would only do a syntactical check of the pattern and always says: no error. In case of optional parts: Only testing by `get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE)` finally helps.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 DateTime API 
 dates can be represented in the following way:

- [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) as year-month-day
- [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) as
  year-month-day-hour-minute-second
- [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) as
  year-month-day-hour-minute-second with time zone

As you can see, there is no way to differentiate between year-month-day-hour-minute-second and year-month-day-hour-minute. So, after the conversion from `String` to `LocalDateTime` is done - you can't differentiate it. The only way to do this is with `String` (either by length or regex), not with `LocalDateTime` object.